# Как передать дополнительные данные в FileReader?

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, файлы

При выборе нескольких файлов запускается цикл в котором читаются файлы.

Поскольку операция чтения асинхронная я не могу узнать что было в переменной **i**
 на момент передачи данных в **reader.readAsText(t[i])**.

Мне нужны данные в **t[i]**. Как их передать в **reader.onload**?

```
var t = this.files, i = 0;
while(t[i]){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadstart = function(){
        console.log(i);
    }
    reader.onprogress = function(e){
        if (e.lengthComputable) {
            var p = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
            if (p < 100) {
                console.log(p);
            }
        }
    }
    reader.onload = function(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
    reader.readAsText(t[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Через замыкание, конечно. Если не ошибаюсь, то это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
reader.onload = (function(i){
    return function(){
        console.log(i);
    }
})(i),
```

Comment: а как передать в ф-ю переменную e(event) которую отдает reader.onload ?